# estimate linear combination of regression coefficients in sas

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I'm using a LMM in SAS and, I would like to get an estimation (and a p-value) of a linear combination of some of the regression coefficients. 
Say that the model is:

b0+b1Time+b2X1+b3X2+b4(Time*X1)

and say that, I want to get an estimate and a p-value for the b1+b4.

What should I do?

Comment: which procedure are you using?

Comment: Generally using ESTIMATE or CONTRAST statements in most statistical procs.

Comment: I'm using proc mixed...